# mux klv data with h264 by mpegtsmux

Tags: gstreamer

I need to mux klv metadata into the h264 stream. I have created application. But the stream is playing only as long as klv-data is being inserted. When i stop pushing klv-data the whole stream stops. **What is the right method to mux asynchronous klv data by mpegtsmux?**

Klv-data need to be inserted into the following working pipeline:

```
v4l2src input-src=Camera ! videorate drop-only=true  ! 'video/x-raw, format=(string)NV12, width=1920, height=1088, framerate=25/1' ! ce_h264enc  target-bitrate=6000000 idrinterval=25 intraframe-interval=60 ! queue ! mpegtsmux  alignment=7 ! udpsink host=192.168.0.1 port=3000 -v
```

This pipeline is collected in the application. To insert klv-metedata appsrc is created:

```
appSrc = gst_element_factory_make("appsrc", nullptr);
gst_app_src_set_caps (GST_APP_SRC (appSrc), gst_caps_new_simple("meta/x-klv", "parsed", G_TYPE_BOOLEAN, TRUE, "sparse", G_TYPE_BOOLEAN, TRUE, nullptr));
g_object_set(appSrc, "format", GST_FORMAT_TIME, nullptr);
```

Then appsrc is linked to the pipeline:

```
gst_bin_add(GST_BIN(pipeline), appSrc);
gst_element_link(appSrc, mpegtsmux);
```

Here is push function:

```
void AppSrc::pushData(const std::string &data)
{
GstBuffer *buffer = gst_buffer_new_allocate(nullptr, data.size(), nullptr);
GstMapInfo map;
GstClock *clock;
GstClockTime abs_time, base_time;

gst_buffer_map (buffer, &map, GST_MAP_WRITE);
memcpy(map.data, data.data(), data.size());
gst_buffer_unmap (buffer, &map);

GST_OBJECT_LOCK (element);
clock = GST_ELEMENT_CLOCK (element);
base_time = GST_ELEMENT (element)->base_time;
gst_object_ref (clock);
GST_OBJECT_UNLOCK (element);
abs_time = gst_clock_get_time (clock);
gst_object_unref (clock);

GST_BUFFER_PTS (buffer) = abs_time - base_time;
GST_BUFFER_DURATION (buffer) = gst_util_uint64_scale_int (1, GST_SECOND, 1);

gst_app_src_push_buffer(GST_APP_SRC(element), buffer);
}
```

Gstreamer version is 1.6.1.

What can be wrong with my code? I'd appreciate your help.

I can push dummy klv-packets to maintain video stream. But i don't want to pollute upcomming stream and i am sure there should be more delicate solution.

I have found that i can send event with [GST_STREAM_FLAG_SPARSE](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstEvent.html#GstStreamFlags), which should be appropriate for subtitles. But as a result i have no output at all.

```
GstEvent* stream_start = gst_event_new_stream_start("klv-04");
gst_event_set_stream_flags(stream_start, GST_STREAM_FLAG_SPARSE);
GstPad* pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(GST_ELEMENT(element), "src"); 
gst_pad_push_event (pad, stream_start);
```

While debugging i have found that after applying the following patch to the gstreamer and using GST_STREAM_FLAG_SPARSE, the stream doesn't stop when the appsrc stops pushing packets.

```
diff --git a/libs/gst/base/gstcollectpads.c b/libs/gst/base/gstcollectpads.c
index 8edfe41..14f9926 100644
--- a/libs/gst/base/gstcollectpads.c
+++ b/libs/gst/base/gstcollectpads.c
@@ -1440,7 +1440,8 @@ gst_collect_pads_recalculate_waiting (GstCollectPads * pads)
   if (!GST_COLLECT_PADS_STATE_IS_SET (data, GST_COLLECT_PADS_STATE_WAITING)) {
     /* start waiting */
     gst_collect_pads_set_waiting (pads, data, TRUE);
-        result = TRUE;
+      if (!GST_COLLECT_PADS_STATE_IS_SET (data, GST_COLLECT_PADS_STATE_LOCKED))
+          result = TRUE;
       }
     }
   }
```

Anyway, the receiver stops updating screen 10 seconds after the last klv packet.

Comment: what about setting caps between mpegtsmux and appsrc? just an idea - what about inserting empty buffers when you do not have metadata? I think that mux is trying to synchronize the two incoming streams.. maybe if you set some caps that its just metadata it will stop synchronizing the two..

Comment: @otopolsky Caps "meta/x-klv" is set to the appsrc, so they should propagate to the mpegtsmux, but it doesn't help. And I also think that mux is trying to synchronize the incoming streams. Indeed i think it must synchronize them until it get informed that should not do synchronization. So how to inform mpegtsmux not to wait data on the meta stream?

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of an old thread but,

In my experience though, if there is no queue between the appsrc and the muxer, you will get this behavior. I would change your:

```
gst_element_link(appSrc, mpegtsmux);
```

To this:

```
gst_element_link(appSrc, appSrcQueue);
gst_element_link(appSrcQueue, mpegtsmux);
```

And I'm not sure if the mpegtsmux has the capability for it or not but the muxer that we have used has a property called `do-timestamping` and when that was set to `TRUE` we had a better experience.

Another tip I would give is to use the `gst-inspect` tool to see what options each elements have.